# Autopopulate fields based on a lookup field value from a different object

Tags: trigger

Can anyone help me out with this,

[image]

This is from a custom object " Quotation", The look up field " Main Driver" is a look up to Personal account object. The below fields are as well exists in the personal account. I need whatever value would be choosen in the main driver, automatically the below values will get pop up.

I amm trying to write a trigger for this, but just got stuck,
Error showing as,

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Account.Age__c at line
>   7 column 17

How can i define the Account variable in the Quotation object trigger ?

```
trigger MainDriverRelatedFields on Quotation__c (before insert,before update) {

    for(Quotation__c obj : Trigger.new){

        if(obj.Main_Driver__c!=null) {

            obj.AgeMainD__c=Account.Age__c;

            obj.GenderMainD__c=Account.Contact_Individual_Gender__c;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: As this `custom` object has a lookup and `Account` is already set then instead of creating and setting new fields from `Account` object in `custom` object create formula fields and set there values to desired field values from `Account` object is this makes sense?

Comment: Hi, I cant create formula field, as depends upon another criteria as YES or NO, these values get populated. If the criteria is NO, users need to manually enter the values here. but as formula field we cant enter any values, it wont work, Can you plz suggest a way. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, if I were you, I'd use Formula Fields for this with return type `text` that references the objects data you want to show, rather than using a Trigger.

There's a few reasons for this:

- If you use a Trigger, you'll also need to think about what happens when the object your referencing is updated otherwise it'll be out of date
- Clicks not code, it's faster than coding this functionality given it already exists

The formula field could be as simple as: `Main_Driver__r.Age__c`.

As long as the relationships are there, this for me is an easier and better approach.

To answer why you're getting this error:

> Variable does not exist: Account.Age__c at line 7 column 17

Is because you're not querying the `Account` object in any way. You'd need to either write a SOQL query to get the account, or you should be able to reference the account via the Lookup field. For example:

```
obj.AgeMainD__c = Main_Driver__r.Age__c;
obj.GenderMainD__c = Main_Driver__r.Contact_Individual_Gender__c;
```

Because you said:

> The look up field " Main Driver" is a look up to Personal account object

If main `Main_Driver__c` is indeed a `Lookup(Account)`, that field looks to the Account object, thus you don't need to specifically say anything about referencing Account in your code because you basically already have.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that, if you need to grab data from any other object besides the object the trigger is on, you'd need to query for it. I don't think `obj.AgeMainD__c = Main_Driver__r.Age__c;` would compile (should complain that `Main_Driver__r` isn't declared as a variable). I agree that this is probably better accomplished via formula fields.

Comment: @DerekF You may be right actually. I've just seen that this is a `before` Trigger, so I'd expect you'd absolutely have to query for it in that instance. Perhaps an `after` Trigger this way would work? I'm speculating though and would have to try it out.

Comment: Dear Both, Thanks . Actually I cant use formula field here, because everytime its not going to populate, it depends upon another criteria field " Are you Driving" , If YES, then it will populate, if NO, then users have to manually enter the values. As formula field doesn't allow re-entering. I think I have to write a trigger. I tried the process builder but its not working although it seems everything is correct. So let me try to query Account and try here, if it will work. Will update you for your suggestions.

Comment: Let me try an after trigger, if the way mentioned will work, else have to query the account.

Comment: @DerekF, You are right, even after putting " after insert" its showing " Main_Driver__r isn't declared as a variable" So, I think I need to query the Account. Let me try that.

Comment: Dear Both, I tried to write the trigger but its showing error, Can anyone plz rectify whats the issue is, Thnx

Comment: trigger MainDriverRelatedFields on Quotation__c (before insert,before update) {

Quotation__c newQuote=new Quotation__c();
 
for(Quotation__c obj : Trigger.new){
newQuote=obj ;
      
  
        

    }
    List<Account> Acc= [SELECT id,Age__c, Acccidents_in_the_last_12_mnths__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN: newQuote.Main_Driver__r]; 
     if(newQuote.Main_Driver__c!=null) {
            newQuote.AgeMainD__c=Acc.Age__c;

            newQuote.Accidents_in_the_last_12_mnthsMainD__c= Acc.Acccidents_in_the_last_12_mnths__c;

        }
}